# Node.js with SQS: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

What am I missing? Do I need to use some specific credentials?
I looked at:
[Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487105/access-to-the-resource-https-sq)

What am I missing? Do I need to use some specific credentials?
I looked at:
[Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487105/access-to-the-resource-https-sqs-us-east-1-amazonaws-com-is-denied)

This is just policy issues of the current queue or there is something in my code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add IAM permission to my user. Thanks.